# Kubernetes - two pods (2/4) receiving same request

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm running k8s and I noticed something strange.

one of my services calls a webhook which is integrated with google chats so that if my service receives a request, it notifies me via google chats along with the details of the request.

Now yesterday, I received two notifications from google chats with the details in the request being exactly the same.

I investigated the issue and aggregated the logs from the pods of that particular service and found that the request was in the logs twice.

I then checked the logs for each pod for that service and lo and behold, two pods had logged processing the request. In fact, that particular endpoint creates a row in the database and there it was, two records created, one immediately after the other.

My question is: Is this a common occurrence with k8s? How could this happen? Has this happened to anyone else before?

Comment: Hello @Ayudh Could you please describe what you think is wrong in this situation? As far as I understand, your service received 2 calls, which is confirmed by information from the google chat. After that, 2 pods processed these requests - one for each.

Comment: The issue is that stripe only made one request to my webhook. How come two pods processed the same request? I thought the requests are loadbalanaced to different pods?

Comment: Could you provide more information about your system - how you deployed it, how it suppose to work? It would be good, if you can provide info for [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce it.